# Multiple reference fixture range @user{1..10}

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, fixtures, nelmio-alice

https://github.com/nelmio/alice/blob/master/README.md#multiple-references

```
group{1..10}:
members: @user{1..10}
```

this example is giving problem

> Entity with Id @user_{1..2} and Class
>   Eggs\CoreBundle\Entity\User not found

It is putting as it is. If i change it to **@user_*** or **@user_1**, this works fine, but above range is giving me problem.

Code:

```
user_{1..10}:
email (unique): email()

group_{1..10}:
user: @user_{1..10}
name: name of the group
```

user: @user_{1..10} <--- this line gives problem. (I have change **business to user**)

Comment: How do you create the users?

Comment: first I create the users fine, then i want to assign them to group. so one user would have 10 group.  so total would be 100 group (10 per user)

Comment: Please add all your code, the error is about `@business_{1..2}` but this reference is not defined in the code of your question.

Comment: Hi @Basit, in the installation section the bundle suggest to use in conjunction with  hautelook/alice-bundle or h4cc/alice-fixtures-bundle. Do you use any of this? Do you use any of it?

Comment: Yes hautelook/alice-bundle

Comment: Why don't you first create the necessary 10 groups and then start creating users? Or all of the groups are per user (rather than global groups)?

Comment: @tftd all the groups are per user. 10 groups per user.

Comment: Do you have a method which accepts an `ArrayCollection` of  `users` in your `Group` entity?

Answer (score 2):

It is not particularly clear from Alice fixtures' documentation, but this syntax is for when you want to pass *an array of users*. Does your `$group->user` field accept array?

If you want each group to get one user, the solution would be:

```
group_{1..10}:
    user: @user_<current()>
    name: name of the group
```

Comment: I want to create each group for 10 users, so if there is 10 group, it will = 100 groups.   group (10) x user (10) = 100, your example will create only 10 group and assign user to it by sequence.